# c++ - Text RPG - Checking For Valid Inputs With Functions

Tags: c++, function

Good evening.

I am currently developing a text RPG. I've been trying to work on a function to vet all my inputs, so that a person would not be able to break my program (or have nothing happen) when they type a string outside of the "accepted" ones for my game. I have this so far, but it is automatically printing "That is not a valid input" for all three of my test cases, even if it is valid. The valid function still executes from the string on top of the "not valid input" prints...

*Disclaimer:* I have only been studying C++ for about a month, so I am sure the code for this is very procedural, and not in line with OOP. In my class, we have not covered objects/classes, or even vectors/arrays (I have learned these on my own). So my code may be very redundant...

**I have included all of my code as to get a full understanding of my program.**

### My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// This prints all commands used in-game upon input.
void userHelp(string action) {
    if (action == "HELP") {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Type 'look' to check your surroundings." << endl;
        cout << "Type 'location' to print current area and map." << endl;
        cout << "Type 'check [item]' to interact with items." << endl;
        cout << "Type 'inventory' to check your inventory." << endl;
        cout << "Type 'move [north, west, south, east]' to move." << endl;
        cout << "Type 'talk [person type]' to begin conversation." << endl;
        cout << "Type 'pick up [item]' to pick up items." << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void inputVetting(string action) {
    while (action = true) {
        if (action != "HELP" || action != "LOOK" || action != "LOCATION" || action != "PICK UP BRASS KEY") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "That is not a valid input." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (action != "CHECK TABLE" || action != "INVENTORY" || action != "TALK GHOUL" || action != "PICK UP KEY") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "That is not a valid input." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (action != "MOVE NORTH" || action != "MOVE SOUTH" || action != "MOVE EAST" || action != "MOVE WEST") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "That is not a valid input." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

// This prints description lines for the player to check their surroundings of each room upon input.
// This makes it easy to add & change description lines for each room.
void look(string action, int currentRoom) {
    if (action == "LOOK") {
        if (currentRoom == 1) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "There is a table and lamp in the room." << endl;
            cout << "There is a ghoulish creature standing in the corner." << endl;
            cout << "He seems friendly." << endl;
            cout << "There is a door to the north." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        if (currentRoom == 2) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Description line 1." << endl;
            cout << "Description line 2." << endl;
            cout << "Description line 3." << endl;
            cout << "Description line 4." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

// This prints current player area, and gives visual map of game zone upon input.
void location(string action, int currentRoom) {
    if (action == "LOCATION") {
        if (currentRoom == 1) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "You are currently in room one." << endl;
            cout << "|-----------------------------|" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|          T E S T 1          |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|-----------------------------|" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }

        if (currentRoom == 2) {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "You are currently in room two." << endl;
            cout << "|-----------------------------|" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|          T E S T 2          |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|                             |" << endl;
            cout << "|-----------------------------|" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

// This provides interactions with objects placed according to each area in the game zone upon input.
void checkItem(string action, int currentRoom) {
    if (currentRoom == 1) {
        if (action == "CHECK TABLE") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Description line A." << endl;
            cout << "Description line B." << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to open the drawer?" << endl;
            cout << "(1) Yes\n(2) No" << endl;
            cout << endl;

            string choice;

            cin >> choice;
            boost::to_upper(choice);

            if (choice == "1" || choice == "YES") {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "You open the drawer." << endl;
                cout << "There is a brass key inside." << endl;
                cout << endl;
            } else if (choice == "2" || choice == "NO") {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "You leave the drawer alone." << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

//This simple function allows user to pick up the key in the first game area.
void pickUpKey(string action, int currentRoom, vector<string>& inventory) {
    if (currentRoom == 1) {
        if (action == "PICK UP KEY" || action == "PICK UP BRASS KEY") {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "You have picked up the brass key." << endl;
            cout << "It is now in your inventory." << endl;
            cout << endl;

            inventory.push_back("Brass Key");
        }
    }
}

// This prints description lines for the first game area.
void firstRoom() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "You awake in a dark cabin-like room." << endl;
    cout << "(Type 'help' for commands)" << endl;
}

//This prints description lines for the second game area.
void secondRoom() {
    cout << "Description line 1." << endl;
    cout << "Description line 2." << endl;
    cout << "Description line 3." << endl;
    cout << "Description line 4." << endl;
}

// This helps player move around the first area upon input.
// I've split up the movements into functions per room, for easier altering/flow
void movePlayerFirstRoom(string action, int& currentRoom, vector<string>& inventory) {
    if (action == "MOVE NORTH" && currentRoom == 1) {
        std::vector<string>::iterator it;
        it = find(inventory.begin(), inventory.end(), "Brass Key");

        if (it != inventory.end()) {
            currentRoom = 2;
            cout << endl;
        } else {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "The door is locked!" << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    if (action == "MOVE SOUTH" && currentRoom == 1) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You can't walk past a wall!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (action == "MOVE EAST" && currentRoom == 1) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You can't walk past a wall!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (action == "MOVE WEST" && currentRoom == 1) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You can't walk past a wall!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// This helps player move around the second area upon input.
void movePlayerSecondRoom(string action, int& currentRoom) {
    if (action == "MOVE NORTH" && currentRoom == 2) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "You can't walk past a wall!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (action == "MOVE SOUTH" && currentRoom == 1) {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Juub closed the door behind him." << endl;
        cout << "You can no longer go that way." << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (action == "MOVE EAST" && currentRoom == 1) {
        cout << "You can't walk past a wall!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (action == "MOVE WEST" && currentRoom == 1) {
        cout << "You can't walk past a wall!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

// This provides a for loop to display the items in player's inventory, used in     checkInventory.
void listInventory(vector<string> inventory) {
    for (auto i : inventory) {
        cout << ":: " << i << endl;
    }
}

// This prints out a player's inventory upon input.
void checkInventory(string action, vector<string>& inventory) {
    if (action == "INVENTORY") {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Your inventory contains: " << endl;

        listInventory(inventory);

        cout << endl;
    }
}

// This provides basic mechanics for combat against enemies.
// void attackEnemy;

// This is the dialogues for NPC 1.
void npcOne(string action) {
    if (action == "TALK GHOUL") {
        string choice;

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Ah, hello." << endl;
        cout << "I haven't seen anyone around here in a long time." << endl;
        cout << "Name's Juub. I've been down here trying to find treasure." << endl;
        cout << "Problem is, I haven't found anything..." << endl;
        cout << "... but I have found a monster." << endl;
        cout << "Actually, that's why I'm in this room." << endl;
        cout << "A corrupted spirit chased me into here." << endl;
        cout << "I was lucky enough to lock myself in, otherwise I'd surely be dead." << endl;
        cout << "But... now, that you're here..." << endl;
        cout << "Mind helping me out?" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Do you want to help Juub kill the monster?" << endl;
        cout << "(1) Yes\n(2) No" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cin >> choice;
        boost::to_upper(choice);
        cout << endl;

        if (choice == "1" || "YES") {
            cout << "Excellent." << endl;
            cout << "I wish I could be of help, but I got a bad arm." << endl;
            cout << "Got shot in the Great War by a phaser rifle." << endl;
            cout << "Come back with his essence, and I'll give you a reward." << endl;
            cout << "... oh, yeah. The key to the door is somewhere in this room." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        } else if (choice == "2" || "NO") {
            cout << "Eh, figures..." << endl;
            cout << "Can never trust humanoids, anyway." << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

// This is a small function to get the user's name, used in gameIntro.
void getName() {
    cout << "Please enter your name." << endl;
    cout << endl;

    string name;
    cin >> name;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Welcome, " << name << ". Enjoy the game!" << endl;
}

// This is the introduction prompt of the game.
// This gives players the option to play or quit the game, then sets player's name.
void gameIntro() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "==============================" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to *Love Pits*" << endl;
    cout << "==============================" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    getName();

    cout << endl;
    cout << "..." << endl;
    cout << "..." << endl;
    cout << "..." << endl;
    //  cout << string(60, '\n'); <-- This is an attempt to try and clear screen, not sure if I want to do this.
}

int main() {
    vector<string> inventory;
    int currentRoom;
    string action;

    inventory.push_back("Rusted Dagger");

    while (true) {
        gameIntro();
        currentRoom = 1;
        firstRoom();
        cout << endl;
        // All possible actions/interactions within room one.
        while (currentRoom == 1) {
            if (currentRoom != 1) {
                break;
            }

            getline(cin, action);
            boost::to_upper(action);

            //Provides all possible actions for player.
            checkInventory(action, inventory);
            checkItem(action, currentRoom);
            userHelp(action);
            look(action, currentRoom);
            location(action, currentRoom);
            movePlayerFirstRoom(action, currentRoom, inventory);
            npcOne(action);
            pickUpKey(action, currentRoom, inventory);
            inputVetting(action);
        }
        secondRoom();
        cout << endl;
        // All possible actions/interactions in game area two.
        while (currentRoom == 2) {
            if (currentRoom != 2) {
                break;
            }
            getline(cin, action);
            boost::to_upper(action);

            // Provides all possible actions for player.
            checkInventory(action, inventory);
            checkItem(action, currentRoom);
            userHelp(action);
            look(action, currentRoom);
            movePlayerSecondRoom(action, currentRoom);
            location(action, currentRoom);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Can anyone help me figure out why my vetting function isn't working? Or, if better, what are some things and places I can do them where I can vet the input properly, so the user can only type in commands that will work within the program, otherwise I print out something like "That is not a valid input"? Thanks for any help! I am just trying to improve as much as possible.

Comment: `if (action != "HELP" || action != "LOOK" || action != "LOCATION" || action != "PICK UP BRASS KEY")` -- So if the action **is** "LOOK", it isn't "PICK UP BRASS KEY", and that whole `if` statement becomes `true`.  See the flaw in this logic?

Comment: Not realted to your problem, but ... Please, stop using `std::endl` when all you want to say is `'\n'` (or `"...\n"`). `std::endl` not only inserts a `'\n'` into the stream but also flushes it. If you \*really\* want to flush a stream be explicit and say `std::flush`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh wow, you are totally right. It should be && and not ||. Thank  you!

Comment: @Swordfish Okay, I will begin to implement that more into my work. Thank you for that tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your logic.  How we speak English does not translate into how we apply boolean logic to an `if` statement.

```
if (action != "HELP" || action != "LOOK" || action != "LOCATION" || action != "PICK UP BRASS KEY")
```

Let's say that you input `"LOOK"`.  Here is what that entire `if` breaks down to:

```
 if (action != "HELP" || // true
     action != "LOOK" || // false
     action != "LOCATION" || // true
     action != "PICK UP BRASS KEY") // true
```

Since you apply `||` (`or`) to all of those tests, all that is required is that one of those tests becomes `true` for the whole thing to be `true`.  So that entire `if` becomes `true`, and thus enters the `if` error block.

The fix is to use `&&` (and):

```
if (action != "HELP" && action != "LOOK" && action != "LOCATION" && action != "PICK UP BRASS KEY")
```

Now let's see how this goes if `"LOOK"` is entered:

```
 if (action != "HELP" && // true
     action != "LOOK" && // false
     action != "LOCATION" && // true
     action != "PICK UP BRASS KEY") // true
```

Now, if any of those conditions is `false`, then the whole `if` becomes `false`, thus does not enter the error block.

Compare now if `"ABC"` is entered:

```
 if (action != "HELP" && // true
     action != "LOOK" && // true
     action != "LOCATION" && // true
     action != "PICK UP BRASS KEY") // true
```

Thus `"ABC"` doesn't match any of the choices, thus the `if` becomes true and enters the error block.

---

A further point -- if you had more entries to check, having an endless `if` statement does not scale very well.  Consider putting the words in a table and do a lookup, i.e. an `unordered_set` or similar, and just use `find()` to see if the entry is in the table.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the in-depth reply and explanation. That really helps me. It's working now, thank you!